# javascript split string into equal parts with autocomplete by space

Tags: javascript, regex, variables

It is necessary to divide a line of text separated by symbols into equal parts (this can be done using split or something else) ..
However, you need to ensure the same length of each part, replacing the missing characters, for example _

for example, there is text from blocks separated by #. delimiter ; shows the end of the virtual string of such text can be many and it can have different lengths.

```
var txts = "text tx#text more# text large text #; text t # text more # text more text #"
```

This text should be:

```
var txts = "text tx______#text more____# text large__#; text t______# text more___# text more.._#"
```

This is an example of an option where you need to select the largest line and all other lines should have the same size, supplemented by spaces.

Another option with a given length of each line with the same addition of characters, and any length of the last block before;

```
var txts = "text tx______#text more____# text large last block#; text t______# text more___# text more.._#"
```

Any option will be the solution of the problem.

Comment: Okay, how will we be graded on this?

Comment: When is this homework due?

Comment: Jokes aside. Welcome to StackOverflow! You're expected to try to **write the code yourself**.If you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. You've made a good attempt at a question which is clear and specific, but you've made no attempt yourself, unfortunately.

Comment: Friendly tip, if you ARE going to ask a homework question, try re-writing it in your own words. Not only will you avoid SO users giving you a hard time (it'll be harder for us to tell), but you'll probably gain more understanding of the problem yourself by doing so.

Comment: @StevenGoodman FYI, _homework_ questions are actually on topic here and _should_ be fine, the issue with this question is they have not made the attempt themselves and have just outright asked for the solution, had they tried and failed and asked for help, this question _would've_ (should've) done fine.

Comment: Anyway, homework or not, OP should provide at least whet they have already tried.

Comment: @George I suppose I was addressing more of a cultural aspect, as I've seen good questions with homework origins be ignored due to their copy-paste appearance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var txts = "text tx#text more# text large text #; text t # text more # text more text #";

const pad = len => s => s.padEnd(len);

const result = txts.split('#').map(pad(12)).join('#');

console.log(result);
```

Comment: https://github.com/Financial-Times/polyfill-service/blob/master/polyfills/String/prototype/padEnd/polyfill.js